# Disabling Submit Button, When two fields value are not equal | Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to Reactjs. So, i don't know, what i am doing wrong here. So, i have a parent component, which has an form and an child component. The parent component have some fields for the form and child component have few fields.
The state for the child component is defined in the parent component and it is passing to it as props. So, In the child component, i have Email, Password, Confirm Password fields and a Submit button. Here, what i need to achieve is, when the user gave the same value for Password and Confirm Password field, the Submit Button will Enable. If he gave the different value, the Submit Button should be disabled. Please have a look in my code to understand it clearly.

Thanks in Advance

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FormPartTwo from './FormPartTwo';

 class Form extends Component {
     constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.state = {
             FirstName: "",
             LastName: "",
             Email: "",
             Password: "",
             ConfirmPassword: ""
         }
     }

     handleChange = e =>{
         this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
         })

     }

     handleClick = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
     }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <input 
            type = "text" 
            name = "FirstName" 
            placeholder="First Name"
            value = {this.state.FirstName}
            onChange = {this.handleChange}
            />
            <input 
            type = "text" 
            name = "LastName" 
            placeholder="Last Name"
            value = {this.state.LastName}
            onChange = {this.handleChange}
            />
            <FormPartTwo handleClick={this.handleClick} doChange={this.handleChange} {...this.props}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Form


/---Component Two---/

import React, { Component } from 'react'

class FormPartTwo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input 
           type="email"
           name="Email"
           value={this.props.Email}
           placeholder="Email"
           onChange={this.props.doChange}
           />
           <input 
           type="password"
           name="Password"
           placeholder="Password"
           value={this.props.Password}
           onChange={this.props.doChange}
           />
           <input 
           type="password"
           name="ConfirmPassword"
           placeholder="Retype Password"
           value={this.props.ConfirmPassword}
           onChange={this.props.doChange}
           />

           <input
           type="submit"
           disabled = {this.props.Password ==! this.props.ConfirmPassword}
           onClick={e => this.props.handleClick(e)}
           />

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default FormPartTwo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using input values (e.g. this.props.Password, this.props.ConfirmPassword, ...) in `FormPartTwo` component without actually passing them into component. `<FormPartTwo handleClick={this.handleClick} doChange={this.handleChange} {...this.props}/>`.

What you should to do is to pass this values into `FormPartTwo` component in props, like this.

```
// Form.js

<FormPartTwo 
  {...this.props}
  handleClick={this.handleClick} 
  doChange={this.handleChange}
  {...this.state}
/>
```

Then in `FormPartTwo` component you can create check variable whether or not submit button should be disabled.

```
// FormPartTwo.js

render () {
  const isSubmitDisabled =
    !this.props.Password ||
    !this.props.ConfirmPassword ||
    this.props.Password !== this.props.ConfirmPassword;

  return (
    ...
    <input
      type="submit"
      disabled={isSubmitDisabled}
      onClick={e => this.props.handleClick(e)}
    />
    ...
  )
}
```

Here is the link of working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/r15ojk139n). Hope this helps!

Comment: @JeyanthKanagaraj Glad to help.